# Can't get around warnings with gradle and proguard in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, proguard

I have recently switched from eclipse to Android Studio and started using gradle for my android app.
I have been fighting with some warnings when trying to build my apk in Android Studio for some time now.
Here is the error log:

```
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:(org.apache.commons.collections.BeanMap$5) that doesn't come with an
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
```

My build.gradle

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 24
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }    

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-android.txt'

        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-android.txt'
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.opencsv:opencsv:3.8'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.github.tonivade:tinydb:0.7.1'
}
```

I have tried it with different proguard options, none of them fixed the issue:

```
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.**
-keep class org.apache.commons.**
```

Does anybody have an idea on how to fix this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
-keep class org.apache.commons.** {
    *;
}
```

instead of

```
-keep class org.apache.commons.**
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue still persists.